# Grouping and transposing rows in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have the following df:

[image: df1]

and I am trying to transform it into:

[image: final_df]

I have tried different options using the pivot function, but since it has duplicates (in the Date column which I cannot drop it gives me an error) I have tried using groupby as well but I still haven't found a found to get the df in the structure that I need.

Comment: sounds like this:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.